# How does the `test` instruction work?

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, instructions

If we have:

```
test dword ptr [eax], 2000h
je label1:
```

Is there any value other than `0` in `dword ptr [eax]` that would make the jump take place?

Comment: No 2000h won't work I tried it, it's not cmp. However with 0 the zero flag is sat so je triggers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instruction **test** works like **and** instruction, the only difference is that result is not stored back in to the destination operand.
So the answer is yes. All binary numbers which not have set the 13th bit on memory address [eax], or all numbers present like b'xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xx0xxxxx xxxxxxxx', where x is 0 or 1, there is exactly 2^31 numbers.

Comment: And what does test eax, eax do?

Comment: @BlackBear: **test eax, eax** will set zero flag if **eax** = 0 the some as instruction **and eax, eax** (also effect to the sign and parity flags and clear carry and overflow flags).