# GDB / GNU assembly: test %esi,%esi returns not equal?

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, disassembly

I'm working on a homework assignment. We're given a pre-compiled binary and we have to use `gdb` to get assembly dumps, traverse data structures, view values stored in memory, etc. in order to puzzle out what the binary does. Here are a few lines of disassembler dump from a function call:

```
0x08048e14 <+21>:   test   %esi,%esi
0x08048e16 <+23>:   jne    0x8048e4b <fun6+76>
0x08048e18 <+25>:   jmp    0x8048e5d <fun6+94>
```

I assumed that `test %esi,%esi` would always return a result of "equals" (or, rather, the equivalent statement expressed using the register flags, which I believe is only `ZF` is set?), and that the `jne` instruction would never execute, and instead the program would execute the instruction at line `<+25>`. However, after stepping through these instructions, the program jumps to line `<+76>`! Why does this happen? I am so baffled.

In case it helps explain the answer, here are the register flags after the `test` instruction at line `<+21>` (`ZF` isn't set?)(I still don't know exactly how to interpret the flags):

```
eflags         0x202    [ IF ]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `test` instruction performs a bitwise `AND`, but does not store the result; it only sets the flags.

And `jne` is actually "jump if `ZF` does not equal 0", so here it's testing if `esi` is zero.

Also see [How does the `test` instruction work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458368) and [What does the `test` instruction do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002079)

Comment: SO automatically inserts question titles for its own links.

Comment: @rici Thank you very much for pointing this out :) However just after my posting this answer it shows "enter link description here" XD, which made me quite confused..

Comment: starrify: there are some wierd update issues. If it looks like you've got a previous version, or you're missing a comment you just typed, etc., reload the page and you'll usually get the most recent version.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* I have found my answer:

> `testl b,a` is like computing `a&b` without setting a destination.
>   `ZF` set when `a&b == 0`.

In other words, I was thinking of the `cmp` instruction, which is different from `test`, apparently.

Comment: oh yes that's true. :)